# Change mouse cursor over input elements in HTML

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

I have various HTML elements which are moveable per Drag'n'Drop. To point out the valid areas for dropping the element (to the user) i'm changing the cursors appearance. I do this by simply appling CSS classes via JS which contain a simple "cursor:xxx". This works fine for DIVs and SPANs.

But when I try to do that with a text input or a textarea the cursor just becomes the "|" (text edit cursor).

Is there a way to override this default behaviour or are there any workarounds (without having to replace these elements with any dummies since that would take a lot of time as some functions relay on these elements)

CSS:

```
body.draggingInvalid ,
body.draggingInvalid * {
    cursor:not-allowed !important;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 200px; height: 20px;">
```

Comment: are you using jQuery draggable()?

Comment: It looks like your code works to me.  You have something overriding it elsewhere:  http://tinker.io/5aaa7

Comment: or double-check your selector..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using *!important*

```
input {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

This will override 'cursor' property of all input elements.

**EDIT:**

If this doesn't work, double check your *selector*. You might wanna add space between **body** and **.draggingInvalid**

```
body .draggingInvalid {
}
```

Comment: The OP *is* using `!important`.

Comment: no longer works if it actually did work at some point

Answer (score 0):

first lets create input and give it class named changeCrusor

```
<input id='test' class="changeCrusor" placeholder='nedys answer'>
```

second lets create the class its self (in your case maybe something overrides the default behavior of input you **can use !important but its realy dont recomended way to do things**

```
.changeCrusor {cursor: text !important;}
```